# How do I stop my rectangle from moving outside my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a beginner in javascript and would like some help with this. I have made a moving rectangle inside a canvas and want to learn how I can make my object to stop moving when it touches the edge of the canvas..

My javascript code looks like this:

```js
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;

    context.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
    context.stroke();

    function move(e) {

      if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        xPos += 5;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        xPos -= 5;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        yPos += 5;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        yPos -= 5;
      }

      canvas.width = canvas.width;
      context.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
      context.stroke();
    }

    document.onkeydown = move;
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me with this.

//Oskar

Comment: Calculate the maximum x using `canvas.width - 50`, then do a check for that before changing `xPos`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the simplest solution would be to add an if statement inside of your move(); Detect the side of the canvas and stop the xPos movement if it's equal to zero.

```
function move(e){
  if(e.keyCode==37){
    if ( xPos !== 0 ) {
      xPos-=5;
    } else {
      // rectangle is at the edge, so don't do anything.
    }
  }
  canvas.width=canvas.width;
  context.rect(xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
  context.stroke();
}
```

You could add an if statement into each function to detect top, right and bottom sides of the canvas.

Comment: `if (xPos >= 5)` seems less error prone.